# Information criteria for selecting the number of factors

Tags: r, function, package, dfm

I´m looking for a package in `R` to calculate the information criteria by Bai and Ng for selecting the number of factors in the model. I found `POET`, but it only provides two of three criteria. (see page 201, equation (9) in http://www.econ.nyu.edu/user/baij/econometrica02.pdf)

Does anyone know such a package or function?

Comment: questions asking for tools are generally considered off topic

Comment: Where am I supposed to ask this question?

Comment: Have a look at the various [special interest mailing lists](http://www.r-project.org/mail.html)... Judging from the URL you provided something related to economics might be a good place to start.